# How to use CSS mix-blend-mode if the containers are siblings?

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

How could we use CSS mix-blend-mode, if the background image/video is not the parent of the element which gets the mix-blend-mode?

**For example**

```
<div class="has-video-background">
  <video></video>
</div>
<div class="caption-above-video">
  <h1>This div should have a colored background with a mix-blend mode multiply</h1>
</div>
```

The div with the class .caption-above-video should have a colored background with a mix-blend-mode. But the effect not appears. When using mix-blend-modes somewhere, the element with the blend-mode is the direct child of the parent with the background image, but in this example this is not possible because of a full with and height background video. Also I cannot manipulate the DOM output, because its coming from a page builder.

How could we use CSS mix-blend-mode effects when the containers are siblings?

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet with real examples of the video and the sort of background/color you want on the elements?

Answer (score 1):

Mix-blend-mode does not work with siblings.

The mix-blend-mode CSS property sets how an **element's content** should blend with the content of the **element's parent** and the **element's background**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode#effect_of_different_mix-blend-mode_values

Comment: I don't understand your statement. The mix-blend-mode as you say sets how an element's content should blend with the content of the element's parent and the video is part of the content of the parent in this case.

Comment: that answers my question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74811253/mix-blend-mode-does-not-work-in-the-following-configuration-i-would-like-to-und

Comment: `mix-blend-mode` does work with siblings. When one sibling is positioned behind another that has a `mix-blend-mode` applied, the top sibling element will blend with the bottom sibling element. https://codepen.io/noraspice/pen/PoXvJbN. The MDN definition is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I actually can't see what the problem is.

If you overlay the video with another element (by giving that element position absolute and the same size as the video for example - but there are lots of ways of doing this) and they are siblings (i.e have the same parent) then the mix-blend-mode seems to work perfectly well.

```css
.parent {
  width: 80vmin;
  position: relative;
}

video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.caption-above-video {
  background: red;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="has-video-background">
    <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/movie.mp4" controls autoplay></video>
  </div>
  <div class="caption-above-video">
    <h1>This div should have a colored background with a mix-blend mode multiply</h1>
  </div>
```

The only thing I did 'extra' was to make the overlaying element have pointer events of none so that I could use the controls on the video. If you need pointer events on the overlay then you'll need to implement the video controls yourself e.g. with JS.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it comes down to which div is on top. So by using `position: absolute;` and a `z-index` for example, you add `mix-blend-mode` to the div that is "on top" of the other div.

I added a code snipped so you can see what I've done to accomplish this.

-I did add a container around the two divs for styling purposes for this example.

-Added an extra `div` in the `.caption-above-video` that has the `background-color` and `mix-blend-mode`. This is important if you don't want the `h1` to be affected by the `mix-blend-mode`, because that affects all children too.

Also added an `background-image` to the `.has-video-background` so you can see the result better. This is for demonstration purposes only and as soon as you add the actual video, the result will be the same.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.has-video-background{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/08/09/16/19/sea-7375377_960_720.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.caption-above-video{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

h1{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
}

.background-div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="has-video-background">
    <video></video>
  </div>
  <div class="caption-above-video">
    <h1>Caption</h1>
    <div class="background-div"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Careful, with this example you are doing the mix-blend-mode with the background defined on `.caption-above-video` which is not defined (so transparent) but not with what's on `.has-video-background` (the video)

Comment: I only added a backgourn-color on .caption-above-video as you would like with mix-blend-mode. The .has-video-backgound has a background-image only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: In your example it works, when I create a codepen and check the result. But I cannot adapt this to my real project. There this does not work...and...in general I don't know understand WHY this works running your code, because the containers are siblings. Humm... what's the important and relevant thing to get this to work in your example? Thanks very much by the way :)

Comment: @asored I insist that this example creates a blend between `.background-div` and `.caption-above-video` (its parent), but has nothing to do with `.has-video-background` and its content.

Comment: @Arnau I've simplified this, and this really seems to work here: https://codepen.io/asored/pen/ZEoELbZ or what do you think?

Comment: @asored Can you provide me with a link from your codepen? It's important to make the two divs appear on top of each other and add an extra "background" div to the div you want to add the mix-blend-mode on.

Comment: @Arnau That's exactly what I did except the additional styling to center things.